# cant change the character in c

Tags: c, char

I'm learning c and I have a problem with the following code. I want to convert "Hello" to "H*llo". But the code does not work.
The code does not give an error and does not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int length(char *abc){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < abc[i]; i++);
    return i;
}

int hideAfromB(char *a, char *b){
    int n = 0;
    int aLength = length(a);
    int bLength = length(b);
    for (int i = 0; i < bLength; i++){
        if (a[0+n] == b[i]){
            n = n + 1;
            if (n == aLength){
                for (int j = 0; j < aLength; j++)
                {
                    b[i-j] = '*';
                }
                n = 0;
            }
        }
        else{
            n = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("%s",b);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    hideAfromB("e","Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

I need help.
Thanks.

Comment: `"Hello"` is a *read-only* array. Try `char text[] = "Hello"; hideAfromB("e", text);` ... `text` is not *read-only* and is initialized with a copy from the *read-only* string.

Comment: The replacement function is ok, even if it can be optimized a bit. The `length`  function is bugged, but it will work with short strings ; even if you correct it, you should think about using the standard `strlen` function. The problem is probably in the main function : the string `"Hello"` is a constant and may be write protected ; declaring explicitly a char array may resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- The main issue is that the second argument in `hideAfromB("e","Hello");` is a constant string which can not be modified.
- `for (i = 0; i < abc[i]; i++);`
  This literally iterates through the array until the iterator value is bigger than the value in the array while executing an empty instruction (`;`).
- `size_t` is the proper type for string length.
- You could use [strstr](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm) to find a single character in a string.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int length(char *abc){
    for (int i = 0; i >= 0; i++) {
        if (abc[i] == '\0') {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1; // indicate string end not found
}

int hideAfromB(char *a, char *b){
    int n = 0;
    size_t aLength = strlen(a); // standard function
    int    bLength = length(b); // modified own function
    for (size_t i = 0; i < bLength; i++){
        if (a[n] == b[i]){
            n = n + 1;
            if (n == aLength){
                for (int j = 0; j < aLength; j++)
                {
                    b[i-j] = '*';
                }
                n = 0;
            }
        }
        else{
            n = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n",b);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char hello[] = "Hello"; // the elements of the array can be modified
    hideAfromB("e", hello);
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc -Wall compare.c
$ ./a.out            
H*llo
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the string `"Hello"` is a constant and you can't change it.

As other have stated, declaring explicitly a char array will sove the problem:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int length(char *abc){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < abc[i]; i++);
    return i;
}

int hideAfromB(char *a, char *b){
    int n = 0;
    int aLength = strlen(a);
    int bLength = strlen(b);
    for (int i = 0; i < bLength; i++){
        if (a[0+n] == b[i]){
            n = n + 1;
            if (n == aLength){
                for (int j = 0; j < aLength; j++)
                {
                    b[i-j] = '*';
                }
                n = 0;
            }
        }
        else{
            n = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("%s",b);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char t [] = "Hello";
    hideAfromB("e",t);
    return 0;
}
```

[Link](https://godbolt.org/z/TnsrMEYn9) to the fixed code: